# Is there a way to detect that the taken Firebase token, Is it taken from network call or from cache?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm working with Firebase Message in Web.
According to Firebase about messaging.getToken():

> Initially it makes a network call once retrieved. subsequent calls to
>   getToken will return from cache.

But we see in the code below that every time the page is loaded, it takes the token from messaging.getToken() function (either from the network or from

the cache) and each time it sends to the server (by sendTokenToServer()).

```
 messaging.getToken().then(function(currentToken) {
          if (currentToken) {
            sendTokenToServer(currentToken);
            updateUIForPushEnabled(currentToken);t
          } else {
            // Show permission request.
            console.log('No Instance ID token available. Request permission to generate one.');
            // Show permission UI.
            updateUIForPushPermissionRequired();
            setTokenSentToServer(false);
          }
```

[Link of Code in Github](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/blob/519575991b4737eb856b9c202c3b2e387584c912/messaging/index.html#L137)

I also want to use the topic. subscribing the Token to topic every time, is not optimal.
In that case, I must subscribe token to topic, Every time the page is loaded.

**Is there a way to detect that the taken token, Is it taken from network call or from cache?**

If the taken token is from cache, I will not send the token to the server and also do not subscribe to the topic (Because it's done first.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to know of the token is new or not, you will have to compare its value against a token that you previously cached yourself in local storage.  The API will not give you any indication.

It's not really that bad to just send it to the server every time anyway.